# issue in passing session value in php pages

Tags: javascript, php, forms, variables, post

i have **quizaction.php** page and **result.php** page. I am passing variables from **quizaction.php** to **result.php**. 
this is my quizaction.php:

```
    <?php

      include 'db.php';
      session_start();
    ?>
    <html>
    <head><title>Quiz Feedback</title></head>
    <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <form name="result" action=result.php  method="POST"> 
      <?php
      $_SESSION['time_left'] = $_POST['formvar'];
      $_SESSION['time_taken'] = 60 - $_SESSION['time_left'];
      ?>
     <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Done" >
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and my **result.php** is:

```
    <?php 
      session_start();
      include 'db.php';
      include 'quizaction.php';
    ?>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {

          var topic1= "<?php echo $type[0]; ?>";
          var topic2= "<?php echo $type[1]; ?>";

          var score= "<?php echo ($score); ?>";
          alert("check");
          alert(score); 
          alert(topic1);
          alert(topic2);
       }
       </script>
```

but im unable to retrieve value of score from quizaction.php.
Actually im getting data in **quizaction.php** also from other page. But here i dont think there is any problem with that. Please help me out. Even expatiation will work

Comment: seems like you're missing some php tags in quizaction.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script has a lot of issues:

1) In the `result.php` page, you have that html output coming after the page has already rendered the contents of `quizaction.php` which contains the start and end tags of `<html>`. That is not idea.

2) When including one into the other, you have two `session_start()`, which will cause an warning/error. That is not ideal.

3) In `result.php` you have `$type` and `$score` defined, but it's nowhere in either page posted in your sample script.

I think your main problem is organizational. You probably had things working individually and are trying to squeeze them into each other now, which is not the best way to do it. You have too much duplication and duplication means you introduce inconsistency and potential for error. Down the road, you will have a hard time maintaining this.

If possible, use some sort of framework. If that is not something you can do, re-organize your script(s). I would:

1) Make a config file that contains your database, session, and other easy-reference items:

**/config.php**

```
<?php
define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT_DIR',__DIR__);
define('FUNCTIONS',ROOT_DIR.DS.'functions');
# Start session
session_start();
# Include database
require_once('db.php');
```

2) You have to define `$type` and `$score`, I don't know where that is coming from so you have to figure out where that is coming from. Based on your scripts posted, you only have `$_SESSION` and `$_POST` defined.

**/result.php**

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction()
    {
        var topic1= "<?php echo $type[0] ?>";
        var topic2= "<?php echo $type[1] ?>";
        var score = "<?php echo $score ?>";

        alert("check");
        alert(score); 
        alert(topic1);
        alert(topic2);
    }
</script>
```

3) Include `result.php` into the quiz page instead of the other way around.

**/quizaction.php**

```
<?php
# Include the config at the top of the main pages
require_once(__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config.php');
# Move non-view logic before view
# Check if something is set first
if(!empty($_POST['formvar'])) {
    $_SESSION['time_left']  = $_POST['formvar'];
    $_SESSION['time_taken'] = 60 - $_SESSION['time_left'];
}
?>
<html>
<head><title>Quiz Feedback</title></head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<!-- Use quotes here ------v----------v -->
<form name="result" action="result.php"  method="POST"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Done" >
</form>
<?php include(ROOT_DIR.DS.'result.php') ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to results.php

```html
<?PHP PRINT_R($_POST); // For Testing ?>
```

quizaction.php

All Input fields must have names like

```html
<INPUT TYPE=text VALUE='123' name='topic_1'>
```

To make something a session variable

- 1st session_start

- 2nd results.php

```html
<?PHP $_SESSION['topic_1'] = $_POST['topic_1']; ?>
```

This should help you along to where you need to go.